# How to Identify a Power Receptacle

Tags: connector, identification, function-generator

The  [Wavetek 144 HF](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:TEBwdVq3bY4J:www.physique.ens-cachan.fr/laboratoire/materiel/fichiers/wavetek4.pdf+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-beta) frequency generator has an unusual power receptacle that I cannot identify. The link references the manual, which does not name the part. I'm not sure it isn't proprietary. Here is an [image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/donwakefield/8468758622/) of the socket.

[image: socket image]

Is it an [IEC 6320-C5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320#C5.2FC6_coupler) connector?

Failing finding a replacement, any advice on the best/safest way to adapt a regular power tail for this device?

**Update**

My friends and I discussed the options presented here, and finally decided that we would be able to modify the inlet using an IEC inlet and connector cable, trimming the [IEC components](http://www.flickr.com/photos/donwakefield/sets/72157632778468683/) rather than the nice case of the Wavetek. Thanks to Brian Drummond for the advice.

Comment: Is this question hopelessly off-topic for this site? If not, please include advice on improving it when you downvote.

Comment: It's definitely not a C5 cloverleaf connector.

Comment: Identification questions tend to not get closed. If your goal is to just identify the connector, I'd delete the backstory, which isn't really relevant, and sets it up like a consumer electronics question.

Comment: I have this exact same issue. I think it is very much on topic for electrical engineering. My particular interest is whether the leads are polarized as I am temporarily going to make my own cable adapter using potted bullet sleeves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks to me to be a ["163"](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~hilpert/e/powerConn/index.html) obsolete-standard line cord.

[image]

You may want to consider removing the existing socket and hard-wiring a locale-appropriate line cord to the instrument (at your own risk) - make sure that the 'line' goes to the fused path!

Another (perhaps safer) option would be to leave the socket in place (cutting off the wires coming from it), drilling a hole in the chassis and feeding the replacement line cord through a grommet/strain relief that's fitted in the hole.

Comment: I'm considering the second option, failing finding a suitable female plug head. If as you say it is a '163', it sounds like the chances of finding a match over-the-counter are poor.

Comment: Don't give up quite yet - this page http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~hilpert/e/powerConn/index.html has links suggesting possible sources including fairly recent Volex part nos. Apparently it was available with L and N swapped so check and re-wire the plug if necessary!

Comment: Brian, one of the sources I read suggested that swapping L and N was not always a problem, in that the device in question would simply experience a polarity/phase shift. It seems like that would apply to a function generator. Do you disagree?

Comment: Depends where on the planet you are. Here, you can rely on N being 0V give or take, and L being 230+-/10%. Reversing those can stress insulation layers or suppression caps, not a good idea on 40 year old gear. But YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of digging and...

Scroll down to the bottom of [this page](http://www.sphere.bc.ca/test/wallwarts.html)

Comment: Thanks! I also found a supplier through Ebay by searching for "Belden 17952". I've since taken apart the Wavetek, and it seems like a safe/simple task to replace the inlet with an IEC connector, so I may end up doing that.

Comment: Heh, my only problem with the IEC approach is it probably involves filing corners on what looks like a nice stove-enamelled panel...